# Laravel why my Auth log out radomlly

Tags: php, laravel, security, session, authentication

why each time that I navigate on my website between the pages, my authentication system log out alone!?

It uses authentication provides by laravel.

Comment: Are cookies enabled? I do have the same problem while in incognito mode

Answer (score 0):

If Laravel loggin you out like every two hours, try to change `lifetime` option in `config\session.php` to something bigger:

```
'lifetime' => 14400,
```

Comment: No, this is not 2 hours, it is random some time 1 minute or less!